# .htaccess to make urls friendly to search engine

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, seo

I've search for some solution to my problem and I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053938/htaccess-to-create-search-engine-friendly-urls). But it doesn't meet my problem. I'm currently building a website using PHP and I've played around with query string in the url. For example, I have a lot of urls like this:

```
www.example.com?page=something
and also
www.example.com?page=something&action=anything
```

which I want to have only:

```
www.example.com/something
and
www.example.com/something/anything
```

I'm also new to .htacess script so I have no idea what the script means to me even I got some suggestions from Google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of architectures for this.

The most common is `mod_rewrite`. Using a set of `RewriteRule`'s you can redirect traffic however you like.

An example of this would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))? index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

However, management of these rules arguably becomes complex. In your case, you'd have to create another rule for a URL like: `/some/other/page`

Another approach is using the [Front-end Controller Pattern](http://www.mind-it.info/2010/01/18/a-simple-front-end-controller-in-php/). All of your traffic filters through a single place (such as index.php) to be *routed*. If you are running Apache 2.2.17 or greater (which most servers are these days) you can do this in a single line using [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource).

For example:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: when using it I saw my site does not have style or effects anymore. And when i view the source code, I click on the CSS source link, and I am redirect to the same place, again I saw this also in firebug.

Comment: Yes, `RewriteRule` will pick up all traffic. That's probably the issue. I suggest using `FallbackResource` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly rudimentary rewrite with mod_rewrite.  Something like this should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))? index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

The expression `([^/])` means to match everything up to the next `/`.  The `(?:/([^/]+))?` contains the same pattern, but is surrounded by the non-capturing group `(?:/ )?`, which makes the entire second group optional.